# Verificando caractere repetido em lista Python

Tags: python, string, loop, caracteres

Olá!

Estou tentando desenvolver um programa que leia uma string e retorne um booleano se existir caracteres repetidos.

Preciso que chegue nesse resultado:

```
("") // False  
("oo") // False  
("po") // True
("EEEttOo") // False  
("PoiX2@op") // False  
("PoiX2@aP") // False
("PoiX2@p@") // False
("PoiX2@2pa") // False
("PoiX2@pa") // True
```

---

Eu achei que ficaria mais fácil de trabalhar com string, passando-o para uma lista e fazendo uma verificação com for e if porém, eu não estou conseguindo desenvolver uma lógica válida.

```
s = 'Banana'

listastr = list(s)
out = True
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como resolver?

Estou baseando que "p" é diferente de "P" e o fato do " " ter dado False, é devido o sistema exigir uma entrada.

No meu sistema, estou utilizando Regex, então ele busca os caracteres [a-z],[A-Z],[0-9] e alguns caracteres especiais.

Comment: Dá a entender que se uma string não tiver duplicados retorna `True`e se tiver duplicados retorna `False`. Em `""` a string vazia não contem duplicados e retorna `False` e em `"PoiX2@pa"` a string possui uma repetição de `p`, um maiúsculo e outro minúsculo, e retorna `True`. Esses resultados estão corretos?

Comment: Sim, estou baseando que "p" é diferente de "P" e o fato do  " " ter dado False, é devido o sistema exigir uma entrada. No meu sistema, estou utilizando Regex, então ele busca os caracteres [a-z],[A-Z],[0-9] e alguns caracteres especiais. Como eu não encontrei nenhuma expressão regular que não aceite repetição de caractere que funcione, eu estou buscando uma alternativa pelo for e if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa é criar um `set` a partir da string. Como um `set` não permite elementos duplicados, o tamanho dele será menor caso a string tenha algum caractere repetido:

```
def permitido(s):
    if not s: # se a string é vazia, retorna False
        return False
    return len(s) == len(set(s))
 
print(permitido('Banana'))   # False
print(permitido(""))         # False  
print(permitido("oo"))       # False  
print(permitido("po"))       # True
print(permitido("EEEttOo"))  # False  
print(permitido("PoiX2@op")) # False  
print(permitido("PoiX2@aP")) # False
print(permitido("PoiX2@p@")) # False
print(permitido("PoiX2@2pa"))# False
print(permitido("PoiX2@pa")) # True
```

Só tive que incluir uma verificação no início para o casyde string vazia. Caso não seja vazia, aí cria o `set`, e se ele for do mesmo tamanho da string é porque não há caracteres repetidos.

Comment: Show! eu não estava conseguindo desenvolver uma lógica que chegasse nisso, como sou iniciante em python, me perco as vezes. Vi que existe muito sobre verificação de repetição para numero inteiros, onde é adicionado um input e faz a verificação por um if, mas não encontrei sobre caracteres que funcionasse como desejado!

Answer (score 1):

Para pesquisar a ocorrência de um padrão de caracteres em uma string use uma [expressão regular](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

O padrão `(?P<char>.).*?(?P=char)` significa:

- `(?P<char>.)` criação de um grupo de captura, identificado como `char`, correspondendo a um caractere qualquer.
- `.*?` corresponde a zero ou mais caracteres quaisquer.
- `(?P=char)` corresponde pelo primeiro caractere correspondido pelo grupo de captura `char`.

O algoritmo é simples ele usa o método [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#re.compile) para compilar o padrão `(?P<char>.).*?(?P=char)`. Define a função `permitido(s)` que aceita uma string `s` como parâmetro, essa função primeiro testa se `s` é vazio ou composta por espaços retornando `Fase` se o teste for afirmativo e depois faz uma busca com [search()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search) pela primeira ocorrência do padrão retorna um boolean baseado no resultado da busca comparado a igualdade com `None`.

Exemplo:

```
import re                                              #Importa o módulo re para trabalhar com regex.

regex = re.compile(r'(?P<char>.).*?(?P=char)', re.I)   #Compila uma expressão regular para servir como padrão de busca.

def permitido(s):
    if s.strip() == "": return False                   #Se a string for vazia ou composta por espaços retorna False.
    return regex.search(s) == None                     #Busca por correspondência do padrão em s e testa igualdade com None e retorna o resultado desse teste. 
    
print(permitido('Banana'))   # False
print(permitido(""))         # False  
print(permitido("oo"))       # False  
print(permitido("po"))       # True
print(permitido("EEEttOo"))  # False  
print(permitido("PoiX2@op")) # False  
print(permitido("PoiX2@aP")) # False
print(permitido("PoiX2@p@")) # False
print(permitido("PoiX2@2pa"))# False
print(permitido("PoiX2@pa")) # True
```

Comment: Muito interessante!!! o que eu precisava mesmo, é utilizar Regex, pois meu sistema tem uma verificação de senha. Necessitando de um mínimo de caracteres, 1 maiúscula, 1 minúscula, 1 numero e 1 caractere especial. Esses caracteres não devem se repetir. 
Eu encontrei uma expressão regular que atende estes requisitos, com exceção da repetição de caractere. 

^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()+-])[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*()+-]{9,}$

Você sabe como eu introduzo nessa expressão regular, para não repetir caracteres? Neste caso eu considero que "p" é diferente de "P".

Comment: @AlanBertoldo Eu sugiro que use as 2 coisas: primeiro vc verifica se tem um caractere repetido (usando o que foi proposto aqui ou na minha resposta), e depois, se estiver ok, vc usa essa outra regex p/ verificar a senha. Fazer tudo na mesma até dá, mas acho que já está complicado o suficiente :-) De qualquer forma, se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e pq fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, p/ indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu

Comment: Outra alternativa é usar grupos "normais" (sem nome): `re.compile(r'(.).*?\1')`

Comment: @AlanBertoldo, faça sempre o mais simples, nesse caso o mais simples é ter uma função para cada atividade. Uma função que verifique se senha é permitida, outra função que verifique se ela cumpre os requisitos, uma função que cheque a resiliência da senha e outra função para então saber se é válida. Ao meu ver testar se a senha possui 1 maiúscula, 1 minúscula, 1 numero e 1 caractere especial já é outra atividade portanto outra pergunta. Se você fizer essa nova pergunta não hesite em me marcar lá que deixo com certeza uma resposta específica a esse outro problema.

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado pela explicação!!! 

Assim que eu terminar, irei postar o resultado!

Gratidão